# Next/Prev category post in same button

Tags: posts, categories, next-post-link, previous-post-link

i like to put a navigation link in my posts, can you help me?

How can do this? http://prntscr.com/64ksjd

I've this code but, it show 2 hiperlinks, i want 1 hyperlink:

```
    $post_id = $post->ID; // current post id
$cat = get_the_category(); 
$current_cat_id = $cat[0]->cat_ID; // current category Id 

$args = array('category'=>$current_cat_id,'orderby'=>'post_date','order'=> 'DESC');
$posts = get_posts($args);
// get ids of posts retrieved from get_posts
$ids = array();
foreach ($posts as $thepost) {
    $ids[] = $thepost->ID;
}
// get and echo previous and next post in the same category
$thisindex = array_search($post->ID, $ids);
$previd = $ids[$thisindex-1];
$nextid = $ids[$thisindex+1];

if (!empty($previd)){
?>
<a rel="prev" href="<?php echo get_permalink($previd) ?>">Previous</a>
<?php
}
if (!empty($nextid)){
?>
<a rel="next" href="<?php echo get_permalink($nextid) ?>">Next</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: One hyperlink is one hyperlink.  It cannot perform two functions because it is one hyperlink.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Yes i know, 1 hyperlinks is one hyperlinks, but i want to show 1 button to navigation in posts, its thats posible?

Comment: What do you want your button to do? Go to the previous post or the next one? It´s not possible to have one button do both at the same time.

Comment: i must display two buttons :/ Wherever, How can check if first or last post of category?

Comment: In your code above ``if(!empty($previd))`` and ``if(!empty($nextid))`` checks if there is a previous/next post. If there isn't a next/prev post that means you're on the first/last.